# Sync chrome tabs with safari locally

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, safari, icloud

I want to be able to check my open tabs on my iOS devices that I have open on my Mac's Chrome browser. I have looked up if its a possibility to sync Chrome directly with iCloud but its not possibile.

Theres another way I have thought of doing this, and this would be to have my open tabs synced with Safari on my Mac that way I can sync natively and still use Chrome on my desktop. (it only needs to be one way sync, I dont need tabs from my iOS devices back to my Mac)

What I would like to know is if there are programs that do this? but do it locally. I have heard of programs such as xmarks but however I dont want to send any additional information to third parties in the process (either than iCloud, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

My Bad. iOS 6 claims they have iCloud Tabs which can keep track of which pages you have open on your devices so you can pick up directly on your Mac Desktop. I had an iPhone but working with a PC so I never able to use this feature, hence why the workaround above.

Reference here http://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/

---

Mac Chrome - sign in to google

iOS device - download Chrome browser - sign in to google

Set your Sync Setting to Sync everything, and you'd be able to see your history of tabs / pages opened both ways (or multi-device).

This won't automatically open the tabs on your iOS device (or Mac Chrome vice versa), but it will allow you to see what pages you had opened (history) and you can simply pick up from where you left off. (So yes although this is a workaround, this breaks your requirement)

I am aware this breaks your requirement that you don't want to send any additional information to third party (in this case Google), but unless your iOS device can somehow query your local Mac for those information (which may need a 3rd party app anyway on the iOS device) I don't see how this is possible.

Hope this helps.

---

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'd just liket to add you can still do iCloud syncing with a PC. I believe you need download Safari.